# User-less Authentication with React Native and API backend

Tags: node.js, authentication, react-native, passport.js

I'm starting to build a React Native app after having finished my first implementation of a node.js backend.

I was recommended using passport.js for authentication.

I don't know too much about this entire subject, but I do know my needs:

- I can't have any sessions/users
- I'd like to create some type of handshake using the phone's UUID(?)
- I want only my mobile app to be able to address the API (ideally) and for "outsiders" to either be ignored or receive a 403 (ideally ignore? - I'm asking :) )

How do I go about doing that?